# Value of this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have a `this` value inside an if statement, nested inside a my `handleFormChange` function. I've tried to use arrow functions with this function to bind the value of `this` but im getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'author' of undefined
```

From my understanding usually you find the `this` value by looking at where the function containing `this` is called. However, in my case im struggling to work this out. Can anyone explain to me why it is undefined and how to solve this issue? Here is the code:

```
class CommentForm extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)


        var comment={author:'', message:''}
    }


    handleSubmit= (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        var authorVal = this.comment.author;
        var textVal = this.comment.message;
        //this stops any comment submittal if anything missing
        if (!textVal || !authorVal) {
         return;
        }
        this.props.onCommentSubmit(this.comment);
        //reset form values
        e.target[0].value = '';
        e.target[1].value = '';
        return;
    }


    handleFormChange= (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        if(e.target.name==='author'){
            var author = e.target.value.trim();
            this.comment.author = author
        }else if(e.target.name==='message'){
            var message = e.target.value.trim();
            this.comment.message = message
        }
    }

    render() {
    return (

        <form className = "ui form" method="post" onChange={(e)=>{this.handleFormChange(e)}} onSubmit={(e)=>{this.handleSubmit(e)}}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="user..."
              name="author"
              type="text"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="comment..."
              name="message"        
            />
          </div>



          <div className="form-group">
            <button disabled={null} className="btn btn-primary">
              Comment &#10148;
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

    );
  }
}

export default CommentForm
```

Comment: var comment <-- wrong

Comment: You never put comment in `this` in the first place. `this.comment = {author:'', message:''}`

Comment: It's not saying `this` is undefined, it's saying `this.comment` is undefined.

Comment: can someone explain why you need to use `this` when declaring the variable? Previously i have never declared variables using `this` in the constructor unless it was state

Comment: `this` refers to the class instance scope, but if you declare a variable in there, it will be available only on that block scope (constructor) so if you want to retrieve it from another block, it wont be there. the `this` scope is available in all the blocks of that class instance. You should read more about object oriented programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step into learning how to do what you want is to study how React's **State** works ([official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) are great at explaning it).

This example is not complete, but should guide you through the proccess.

```
class CommentForm extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    author  : '',
    message : '',
  }

  this.onChangeAuthorName = this.onChangeAuthorName.bind(this);
  this.onBlurAuthorName   = this.onBlurAuthorName.bind(this);
}

onChangeAuthorName(e) {
  this.setState({ author: e.target.value });
}

onBlurAuthorName() {
  // trim on blur (or when you send to the network, to avoid
  // having the user not being able to add empty whitespaces
  // while typing
  this.setState({ author: this.state.author.trim() })
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <input value={this.state.author} onChange={this.onChangeAuthorName} onBlur={this.onBlurAuthorName} />
    ...
  );
}

}
```

Usually, when you want to "set" variables in React, you don't add them as you do to in Javascript classes (`this.comment = e.target.value`), but instead, use the function setState(). From the docs:

```
// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';

Instead, use setState():

// Correct
this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
```

(NOTE: Alternatively, this could be done using React Hooks, but I recommend you learn the lifecycle methods firsthand. Good luck!)

Comment: I made a similar working example on [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-state-example-yctch?fontsize=14) for the OP.

Assuming that the `props.onCommentSubmit` function is async, it makes sense to clear the form after a successful `then` call on the Promise. If it's synchronous, remove my `then` call and just clear it directly after the submission.

Comment: @ReedDunkle thanks for that! Your example is almost right but needs an important edit! `this.state` should be declared inside the constructor *always*, and `super(props)` should be the first line inside the constructor (unless using hooks). [Here's why, from Dan Abramov himself](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/).

Comment: I was assuming the use of [property-initializer](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/use-property-initializers-for-cleaner-react-components/). But I shouldn't have assumed that. This is maybe more relevant to the use case: [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor). I updated the sandbox to use the `constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write even if you proposed the correct answer for the simple reason that I think my code is closer to what it published.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comment: {},
      some: 1
    };
  }

  handleFormChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { comment } = this.state;
    const newCommentState = function() {
      let returnObj = { ...comment };
      returnObj[this.target.name] = this.target.value.trim();
      return returnObj;
    }.bind(e)();
    this.setState({ comment: newCommentState });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let { comment } = this.state;
    if (!comment.author || !comment.message) return;

    this.props.onCommentSubmit(comment);
    this.setState({ comment: {} });
    e.target[0].value = "";
    e.target[1].value = "";
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          className="ui form"
          method="post"
          onChange={e => {
            this.handleFormChange(e);
          }}
          onSubmit={e => {
            this.handleSubmit(e);
          }}
        >
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="user..."
              name="author"
              type="text"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="comment..."
              name="message"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <button disabled={null} className="btn btn-primary">
              Comment &#10148;
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Live example:

[image: Edit patient-bush-27cp5]