# Why is my state not updating as expected when creating a comment section?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Im trying to create a comment secton, where `this.state` stores all comments made by combining the old state with the new one each time a new comment is submitted. However, im getting very strange behavior in my app which i cant explain. On the first comment submital the comment is sent up from `commentForm` to it's parent `commentSection` using a callback which invokes the parent function `handleCommentSubmit`, updating my `comments` state. Everything renders correctly . However, once the second comment is submitted, the same process occurs; the state is updated, but it doesn't contain the previous first comment. Following this state update, the new state is sent to `commentList` to render the comments. In this case, strangely, the prop `this.state.comments` passed down to it now contains the an array containing 2 of the second comment (see bottom for screenshot). This results in my comment section now showing User 2's comment two times, without displaying User 1's comment. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is the relevent code:

Parent:

```
class CommentsSection extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={comments:[], loading:false}

    }

    componentDidMount(){

    }


    handleCommentSubmit = (newComment) =>{


        var comments = this.state.comments;
        var newComments = comments.concat([newComment]);
        this.setState({comments: newComments},console.log('The current state is now',this.state.comments));
        //comment is object with author and message. Add new comment to old comments
        //this.setState({comments:[...this.state.comments,newComment]},console.log(this.state, 'state updated'))

    }
    //Comments are create in comment form, passed up then sent down through commentList to individual comment rendering inside comment.js
// comment form oncommentsubmit running everytime it renders, not only on submital
    render(){
        const loadingSpin = this.state.loading ? "App-logo Spin" : "App-logo";
        return(
            <div>
                <span><h4> Comments </h4></span>
                <div className="ui grid"> 


                    <div className = "right floated eight wide column" >
                        <CommentList comments={this.state.comments}/> 
                    </div>
                    <div className="left floated eight wide column">

                        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}/>

                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>

        )

    }
}

export default CommentsSection
```

Children:

```
function CommentList ({comments}){

    //need to map over array of comments to format correctly
    console.log('This is what is passed as props to CommentList', comments)
    comments = comments.map((comments)=>{return <Comment key = {comments.message} message={comments.message} author={comments.author} />})

    return(<div>{comments}</div>)
}



export default CommentList
```

```
class CommentForm extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)


        this.comment={author:'', message:''}
    }


    handleSubmit= (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        var authorVal = this.comment.author;
        var textVal = this.comment.message;
        //this stops any comment submittal if anything missing
        if (!textVal || !authorVal) {
         return;
        }
        this.props.onCommentSubmit(this.comment);
        //reset form values
        e.target[0].value = '';
        e.target[1].value = '';

    }


    handleFormChange= (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        if(e.target.name==='author'){
            var author = e.target.value.trim();
            this.comment.author = author
        }else if(e.target.name==='message'){
            var message = e.target.value.trim();
            this.comment.message = message
        }
    }

    render() {
    return (

        <form className = "ui form" method="post" onChange={(e)=>{this.handleFormChange(e)}} onSubmit={(e)=>{this.handleSubmit(e)}}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="user..."
              name="author"
              type="text"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="comment..."
              name="message"        
            />
          </div>



          <div className="form-group">
            <button disabled={null} className="btn btn-primary">
              Comment &#10148;
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

    );
  }
}
```

[image: comment section screenshot]
[image: Console.log]

Comment: You didn't even follow the instructions within the [accepted answer of your own other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58034750/1218980)... Namely, you're not using the state and you're mutating the DOM directly.

Comment: Rightly said. Saw the other question. It covers most of the mistakes made here too :)

Comment: do you know why having an uncontrolled component would lead to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({comments: [...prevState.comments, newComment]}))
```

Comment: im still getting the same issue once implementing this

Comment: would be nice if you provide an example on code sandbox

Comment: While this may be a solution to the original issue, you should provide context and an explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**.

You are storing `author` and `message` on instance variable ( `this.comment`) of the `<CommentForm />` component.The `this.comment` maintains the same memory location even after re-renders. So even after re-rendering, it's the same object. You are just overwriting the properties of that object. And your parent state is a comments array, where each element is just a pointer to the same `this.comment` object that gets overwritten every time.

Have a look at the link, keep adding comments to see what's happening to the parent component's state
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cubmcf

**Solution**

Modify handleSubmit to like this.

```js
handleCommentSubmit = newComment => {
  var comments = this.state.comments;
  // var newComments = comments.concat([newComment]);
 this.setState({
   comments: [...comments, newComment]
 });
 
};
```

Update Comment form to use state rather than instance variables.

Changes made

1. Removed update dom element directly.
2. Used controlled components for input fields
3. Some general refactors.

```js
class CommentForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { author: "", message: "" };
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {author, message} = this.state;
    //this stops any comment submittal if anything missing
    if (!author || !message) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({ author, message });
    this.setState({author: "",  message : ""})
  };

  handleFormChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});    
  };

  render() {
      const {author, message} =  this.state;
    return (
      <form
        className="ui form"
        method="post"
        onChange={e => {
          this.handleFormChange(e);
        }}
        onSubmit={e => {
          this.handleSubmit(e);
        }}
      >
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="user..."
            name="author"
            type="text"
            value = {author}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="comment..."
            name="message"
            value={message}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <button disabled={null} className="btn btn-primary">
            Comment &#10148;
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you know why instance variables helped caused this issue, but using state would solve it?

Comment: Because they refer the same object even after rerenders. Thats why you see duplicates after adding.I used state here and I'm resetting the state to a new object after submit  comment

Comment: Updated the answer to provide an explanation for the issue. Hope it helps. Please mark as correct/upvote if found useful

Comment: thanks for the response. Im still struggling to understand how each element of the comments array points to the same object though. Surely if it is receiving the `newComment`s prop each time a new form is submitted, it should have different entries in each element? I was finding that when console logging the value of `this.comment` just before it was passed up, it contained one set of entries for the current comment, rather than 2 sets of the same comment. How therefore is `commentList` duplicating the comment?

Comment: I will update my answer to cover what is wrong with your code in more detail. Need some time. You can check back later.

Comment: thanks. I'm basically just trying to understand the process that went on in my code which was causing these issues. That might help my understand how these changes would solve the problem